# HP Smart Array P410i, two drives faulty in a short time window

Tags: hard-drive, raid, raid-1

I have a P410i with two disks in RAID 1 configuration.

After some time, a third standby disk was added.

Then, one of the two disks failed, and we ordered a replacement disk. Unfortunately the part was out of stock and supply was delayed. I thought this of little importance, except that a week later, while we were waiting for the disk to arrive "any day now", and well after the array had re-synced, *the second disk failed too* (I had not removed the failed disk even after syncing finished, and I planned on pulling it out and replacing it in one fell swoop).

Now, the array is running on the third disk. I've placed an order for another *two* disks, but aren't going to wait for them - the first replacement arrived today.

This is RAID1, not RAID5; I am *reasonably* confident that nothing has changed and I can pull both failed disks out at the same time, and push the replacements in. The third disk should (after a while) go back to being a hot standby drive.

Are my assumptions correct, or is there something I should be aware of?

Also, the third disk was purchased from the same supplier and from the manufacture date it is two months older than the two failed disks. Should I be planning on purchasing a further replacement, even if it spent all its life in a standby slot and is currently (touch wood) working, just to be sure? I've had disks straight out of the package fail on me inside of a week, so also replacing the disks is not risk-free.